# C# - Generic Lists - Can't Clear and Add all over Again 

Tags: c#, sql, list

The Problem is ..
I have a Set of Lists IDs .. Each one Related to Set of Traffic IDs in the Database ..

I wanna Use One List ID for each loop to get that set of TL IDs and store them in a List but in a Class-seem manner !

when I don't add `TL_ids.Clear();` at beginning .. all results are added so the final result becomes = Count of all Traffic lights ids ..

and when I clear before `Par.Clear();`
all results came back with Zeros .

Any help ?

```
List<int> TL_ids = new List<int>();
List<string> TL_Desc = new List<string>();

//Array That will Hold Role ID.
ArrayList Par = new ArrayList();
//Get All Traffic Lights info. , but based on Iteration of Lists IDs.
for (int i = 0; i < List_IDs.Count; i++)
{
  Par.Clear();
  Par.Add(new SqlParameter("@List_id", List_IDs[i].ToString()));
  SqlDataReader Dr = GetTLs.ExecSPSelect_dr("GetTLsByListID", Par);

  while (Dr.Read())
  {
    //Fill Intermediate Lists.
    TL_ids.Add(int.Parse(Dr[0].ToString()));
    TL_Desc.Add(Dr[1].ToString());
  }

  ALL_TLsBy_Lists.Add(new Lists(List_IDs[i], TL_ids, TL_Desc));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope I got your question right.

Lists are passed by reference.

You would have to create a new List in each iteration when creating `new Lists(...)`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < List_IDs.Count; i++)
{
  TL_ids = new List<int>();
  TL_Desc = new List<string>();
  ...
}
```

Otherwise, you end up with several `Lists` objects with the same `TL_ids` and `TL_Desc`!

So if you clear `TL_Desc` in the last iteration, you will get an empty list in all your `Lists` objects.